# Eclipse RCP 3.7 - feature icon in the about dialog does not apear

Tags: eclipse-rcp, about-box

[image]

I followed [this](http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/09/branding-an-eclipse-plugin/) tutorial, but the feature icon does not apear in the about dialog.
What could be the reason?

1. I have created one feature-X-based product.
2. I defined a plugin Y as feature X's branding plugin
3. I added about.ini and an 32x32 px icon to the plugin.

about.ini:

```
aboutText=Dicke Alice
featureImage=images/icons/icon_32x32.png
```

Comment: Have you added the about.ini and the icon files to Binary Build in `build.properties` file?

Comment: One more question: have you deployed your feature and than install it in Eclipse? or maybe you run your feature (and plugins) from Eclipse? In the second case the feature image is not shown (but I don't know why).

Comment: It's the second case. So after deployment the feature will show up?

Comment: Everything else looks fine, so the featurs should show up after deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the feature's image will only show up after deployment, but not when started from IDE.