# Branding your Eclipse plug-in application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want my Eclipse plug-in product to have the icons/images as per the link:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html

The link is for a RCP applications, but I have used it as follows:

```xml
<extension id="ide" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products"> 
    <product name="SuitA" application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" description="SuitA Beta"> 
        <property name="windowImages" value="icons/projectRoot.png,icons/projectRoot.png"/> 
        <property name="aboutImage" value="icons/projectRoot.png"/> 
        <property name="aboutText" value="SuitA Beta"/> 
        <property name="appName" value="SuitA"/> 
    </product> 
</extension>
```

When I launch it - I am not able to see modified window images , icons?

Comment: Launch what? What exactly are you telling Eclipse to run?

Comment: I have added all the required plugins in dropin folder for a min. binary release and launching the eclipse.

Comment: Yes but what product / application id are you telling Eclipse to run? It will only use these settings if you run product id 'your-plugin-id.ide'

Comment: Can't find proof but if I recall correctly, you need to _build_ the product to see the the branding. It is not applied when launching from within the IDE.

Comment: @ greg-449 - I have added this to .eclipseproduct file >>>name=SuitAid=SuitACore.ideversion=1.0.0. Is this info. not sufficient to pick up the settings?

Comment: @Rüdiger Herrmann - How to build a eclipse application - i have just put all the plugins in dropin folder in a min. binary release.

Comment: I think what he (@Rüdiger Herrmann) means is that you should not just launch your application from the Eclipse toolbar. Instead you have to open the .product file and click the Launch icon there. It usually fixed problems like these.

Comment: @Amrit IIRC in order to see the branding you need to export your feature or product and then install it from the resulting p2 repository into an existing Eclipse product. Meaning , you'd have to take the same steps that a regular user of your _plug-in_ would take in order to install it. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415139/eclipse-rcp-3-7-feature-icon-in-the-about-dialog-does-not-apear)